# How to delete duplicate rows in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How can I delete duplicate rows from Azure Synapse Analytics? I'd like to delete one of the rows where **audit_date = '2022-08-10'** and **city = 'LA'**. I'd like to keep only 1 row. I've tried using the CTE method( Row_number()... ). Unfortunately, SQL Pool doesn't support Delete statements with CTE.

| audit_date | city | number_of_toys | number_of_balloons | number_of_drinks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-10 | LA | 35 | 100 | 40 |
| 2022-08-10 | NY | 20 | 70 | 30 |
| 2022-08-10 | LA | 35 | 102 | 40 |

Answer (score 1):

- You can do this using `DELETE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`. I have created a similar table with the sample data that you have given.

[image]

- Now use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to partition by `audit_date` and `city` based on your condition.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY audit_date,city ORDER BY audit_date,city) AS row_num FROM demo where audit_date='2022-08-10' and city='LA'
```

[image]

⦁   You can use the following query to complete the delete operation only on the rows where `row_num > 1`.

```
DELETE my_table FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY audit_date,city ORDER BY audit_date,city) 
AS row_num FROM demo where audit_date='2022-08-10' and city='LA'
) my_table
where row_num>1
```

[image]

This way you can delete duplicate records by retaining one row using `DELETE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` as demonstrated above.

Comment: In dedicated SQL pool, this does not work unless the table is HASH, according to the error I am receiving: 
"The query processor could not produce a query plan because the target DML table is not hash partitioned."